# Importing a python module from another directory

Tags: python, import, directory

The below is what my folder for my project looks like. The code itself relies on the files that are contained within the Project folder - so my question is simple.

What is the simplest way to use `import Maths` from a differant directory? I have gotten it to work before, but it never loads the files as well.

```
Project (Main Folder):

resources
    bg.png
    student.png
    stylesheet.css
    template.html

configFile.pickle
Maths.pyw
userKeycodes.pickle
```

Answer (score 2):

add project folder to sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/project/folder')
import Maths
```

Comment: Tried this, it does not load the files in the folder.

Comment: also for project folder to be treated as python module you have to add `__init__.py` ( can be empty )  to the project folder. Interpreter will then find Maths submodule

Comment: Have tired this too.. doesent seem to do anything